# Shell command to count pages in a PDF (other than pdftk)?

Tags: terminal, bash, pdf, command-line

I have been using this to get a page count of PDFs in shell scripts in OS X:

`pdftk "$i" dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{print $2}' | tr -dc '[0-9]'`

(where `$i` is the PDF filename)

However, there are times when that does not seem to work, so I would like to find another way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another `exiftool` solution:

```
cd /path/to/pdf/directory
exiftool -T -filename -PageCount -s3 -ext pdf .
```

Comment: This one is very good IMHO. It (1) is simple (2) produces a clean output: file name [spaces] page count (3) can process all pdf files in a dir even if there are other files (4) will probably work on computer with different locales (5) is portable to other systems (using it on Linux).

Comment: Great solution! Using this right now to count pages in thousands of files recursively and pipe the output to a file. Command is then like this: `exiftool -T -r -filename -PageCount -s3 -ext pdf . > pages.txt`

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use `mdls` to view the metadata attributes for a PDF:

`mdls -n kMDItemNumberOfPages "$i" | cut -c24-`

Comment: Note: This solution only works if the target file resides on a volume/location that's being indexed.  Personally, I have some locations excluded so for me this would not work in some cases.  That said, it's a better way then having to pipe it so many times like shown in the OP. It's worth a +1 though! :)

Comment: Even easier: `mdls -raw -name kMDItemNumberOfPages` I didn't realize there was an attribute for this. All of my files are on indexed HFS+ devices, so that will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) command line utility to count the number of pages in a PDF document. `qpdf` can be installed via Homebrew via running the following command:

`brew install qpdf`

Once installed, to count the number of pages execute:

`qpdf --show-npages file.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

Whether the file is indexed or not this works however if the target file does not resides on a volume/location that's being indexed then here is an alternative to the excellent solution presented by jordanmerrick.

I just tried this using [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and if it's just the page count you want as a number then this works:

```
exiftool "$i" | awk -F": " '/Page Count/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

mdls did not work for me either.  I did this on a Mac, but I expect it'll be the same on any bash or similar shell.  With the Mac I have homebrew already installed so I just typed the command "homebrew install exiftool" first.

Here is the script I ran, you can set it up for your purposes.  I had a whole folder of PDF files and I wanted page counts on every one of them so I had it look through the files and print out the filename and page with a , in between

```
#!/bin/sh

FILES=/path/to/files/*
for f in $FILES
do
    fn=$(basename "$f")
    printf "$fn"
    pg=$(exiftool "$f" | grep 'Page Count' | cut -c35-)
    printf ",$pg\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the `pdfinfo` command from the [xpdf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277784/17800) package. Once installed, you can get the number of pages alongside the file name as follows:

```bsh
pdfinfo /path/to/file.pdf | grep -- ^Pages
```

Or as a batch run (with the output format you asked for):

```bsh
while read pdf; do 
    pages=$(pdfinfo "$pdf" 2>&1 | grep -- ^Pages | tr -dc '[0-9]')
    printf "%s %d\n" "$pdf" "$pages"
done < <(find /path/to/pdfs -name "*.pdf" -noleaf -type f)
```

`pdfinfo` in general outputs the following information:

```
Creator:        Microsoft� Office Word 2007
Producer:       Microsoft� Office Word 2007
CreationDate:   Tue Feb 25 14:46:56 2014
ModDate:        Tue Feb 25 14:46:56 2014
Tagged:         yes
Form:           none
Pages:          3
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.32 x 841.92 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      102155 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

I use it frequently to check if the pdf is "optimized" or not. In case it's not optimized, I can then run it through the following script to reduce its file size (often significantly):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# makeSmall.sh 

input=$1
output=$2
 
gs \
  -o $output \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.8 \
  -dDetectDuplicateImages=true \
  -dEmbedAllFonts=false \
  -dSubsetFonts=true \
  -dConvertCMYKImagesToRGB=true \
  -dCompressFonts=true \
  -dNOPAUSE \
  -dQUIET \
  -dBATCH \
  -c '<</AlwaysEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams' \
  -c '<</NeverEmbed [/Courier /Courier-Bold /Courier-Oblique /Courier-BoldOblique /Helvetica /Helvetica-Bold /Helvetica-Oblique /Helvetica-BoldOblique /Times-Roman /Times-Bold /Times-Italic /Times-BoldItalic /Symbol /ZapfDingbats /Arial]>> setdistillerparams' \
  -f $input
```

```
$ pdfinfo F.pdf | grep -- ^Optimized
Optimized:      no
$ ./makeSmall.sh F.pdf F-reduced.pdf 2>/dev/null
$ gstat --printf "%13n [size=%6s Bytes]\n" F*.pdf
F-reduced.pdf [size= 15983 Bytes]
        F.pdf [size=102155 Bytes]
```